# Force LibreOffice to use Kde integration?

Tags: kde, i3, libreoffice

I am using i3wm and Libreoffice. I have already installed the libreoffice-kde package.
Currently LO seems to be integrating with gnome by default, but I was wondering if there is a way to force it to use KDE integration?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to remove any other integration packages and leave only libreoffice-kde integration. How you do it depends on your distribution (I'm assuming you are running linux).

As an example if you are using ubuntu you need to execute the followings

```
 sudo apt-get install libreoffice-kde
 sudo apt-get purge libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-gtk3
```